# How to update conemu settings with commandline

Tags: conemu, chocolatey

I am writing a chocolatey package, that should install my conemu settings. How to apply them in command line?

- If I use xml, I need some command to apply and save settings when conemu is not running, also I need to find conemu location
- If I use .reg, the settings are merged to registry, but already installed version of conemu uses settings.xml on the disk

Comment: Purpose? ConEmu does not ship neither xml nor .reg settings. Just copy your file to appropriate place.

Comment: I install all my environment on VM with a single command \\MyMachine\choco\get my.environment , I'd like to just include conemu settings to package and forget about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at https://chocolatey.org/packages/EthanBrown.ConEmuConfig, it does very similar to what you need. It's an older package that was up before we started capturing the package files on dot org, but you can download it with the download link (in the sidebar) and then unzip it to see the contents.